# How to fix multiple data points for a single observation in a column?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Just a heads up, I'm working with a very odd data frame, and I'm struggling to adjust it into a usable format.

Basically, I have a grouping variable `Game`, an individual-level variable `Player`, and `Player_Grade`, which takes on an atypical format.

Here is an example:

```
Game    Player                            Player_Grade
1       ABA 02        ABA 02 (+1.5); ABA 04 (+0.2); ABA 46 (+3.0)
1       ABA 04        ABA 02 (+1.5); ABA 04 (+0.2); ABA 46 (+3.0)
1       ABA 46        ABA 02 (+1.5); ABA 04 (+0.2); ABA 46 (+3.0)
2       ABA 02        ABA 02 (+1.2); ABA 04 (+3.2); ABA 46 (+8.1)
2       ABA 04        ABA 02 (+1.2); ABA 04 (+3.2); ABA 46 (+8.1)
2       ABA 46        ABA 02 (+1.2); ABA 04 (+3.2); ABA 46 (+8.1)
3       BRS 03        BRS 03 (+1.7); BRS 05 (+1.2); BRS 01 (+2.5)         
3       BRS 05        BRS 03 (+1.7); BRS 05 (+1.2); BRS 01 (+2.5)
3       BRS 01        BRS 03 (+1.7); BRS 05 (+1.2); BRS 01 (+2.5)
```

So as you can see, every observation within the group variable has the same value for the `Player_Grade` column. What I would like to do is create a new column that assigns the correct grade (the number in the parentheses) to each player. So the above table would become:

```
Game    Player                            Player_Grade               Grade 
1       ABA 02        ABA 02 (+1.5); ABA 04 (+0.2); ABA 46 (+3.0)     1.5
1       ABA 04        ABA 02 (+1.5); ABA 04 (+0.2); ABA 46 (+3.0)     0.2
1       ABA 46        ABA 02 (+1.5); ABA 04 (+0.2); ABA 46 (+3.0)     3.0
2       ABA 02        ABA 02 (+1.2); ABA 04 (+3.2); ABA 46 (+8.1)     1.2
2       ABA 04        ABA 02 (+1.2); ABA 04 (+3.2); ABA 46 (+8.1)     3.2
2       ABA 46        ABA 02 (+1.2); ABA 04 (+3.2); ABA 46 (+8.1)     8.1
3       BRS 03        BRS 03 (+1.7); BRS 05 (+1.2); BRS 01 (+2.5)     1.7 
3       BRS 05        BRS 03 (+1.7); BRS 05 (+1.2); BRS 01 (+2.5)     1.2
3       BRS 01        BRS 03 (+1.7); BRS 05 (+1.2); BRS 01 (+2.5)     2.5
```

One way I thought about doing this was to create a new column for each player, then coalesce those columns together into a single column. But since my full data set is 100s of different players, each with many different grades, such a process would be impractical.

Again, I'm a little lost so any help setting me in the correct direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

MRE:

```
structure(list(Game = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Player = c("ABA 02", "ABA 04", "ABA 46", "ABA 02", "ABA 04", 
    "ABA 46", "BRS 03", "BRS 05", "BRS 03"), Player_Grade = c("ABA 02 (1.5); ABA 04 (0.2); ABA 46 (3.0)  ", 
    "ABA 02 (1.5); ABA 04 (0.2); ABA 46 (3.0)  ", "ABA 02 (1.5); ABA 04 (0.2); ABA 46 (3.0)  ", 
    "ABA 02 (1.2); ABA 04 (3.2); ABA 46 (8.1)  ", "ABA 02 (1.2); ABA 04 (3.2); ABA 46 (8.1)  ", 
    "ABA 02 (1.2); ABA 04 (3.2); ABA 46 (8.1) ", "BRS 03 (1.7); BRS 05 (1.2); BRS 01 (2.5)", 
    "BRS 03 (1.7); BRS 05 (1.2); BRS 01 (2.5)", "BRS 03 (1.7); BRS 05 (1.2); BRS 01 (2.5)"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code takes values in the 'Player' and 'Player_Grade' column for each row. It then replaces the value in parentheses closest to the value in 'Player' column.

```
mutate(df,Grade = purrr::map2(Player_Grade,Player,
                         function(x,y) sub(paste0(".*",y," \\(((\\+|\\-)*[0-9\\.]+)\\).+"), "\\1", x)))
```

Comment: so I think your code is very close to working my data. I just need to change one thing in my data above--I forgot that the grades generally have a plus or minus sign in front of them to indicate if they are positive or negative. So right now, your code only works on plays that are exactly zero (because there is no plus sign or negative sign). Is there any way to adjust your code so that it can just put the string value inside the parentheses into the new column? I'll update my data again to reflect this

Comment: Edited it. Could you try the new one?

Comment: just tried it. Now it works when there is a plus or minus before the number but not when the number a 0.0 haha. Any way to fix this?

Comment: What about now?

Comment: wow as far as I can tell, it worked! You're amazing, thanks so much!

Comment: May I ask, how is it able to work without grouping?

Comment: Let me edit the answer a bit to explain :)